# How can I represent the summation $\frac{x}{1^2}+\frac{x^2}{2^2}+\frac{x^3}{3^2}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm looking to represent the summation $\frac{x}{1^2}+\frac{x^2}{2^2}+\frac{x^3}{3^2}+\cdots$ in the form of

$$\frac{3}{2}\arctan^2\left(\sqrt3(a_1x+a_2x^2+ a_3x^3+ \cdots)\right)$$

I wanted to represent the Basel problem as an inverse trigonometric function. (Here at x=1, the value $(a_1+a_2+ a_3+ \cdots)$ must equal 1, so both sides equal $\pi^2/6$)

If the $,a_1,a_2,a_3...$ coefficients followed a set pattern, the Basel problem may alternatively be proved by proving that the sum of coefficients equals $1$.

I attempted to evaluate the coefficients by comparing derivative values of LHS and RHS at x=$0$, however the complexity soon skyrocketed.

Is there a more efficient way of evaluating the Taylor series, like substituting x as another trigonometric function or is the problem inherently not representable using elementary functions?

Comment: I tried a variety of combinations, eg $LHS=arcsin((a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...)/2)*arcsin(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...)$ 
$(arcsin(1/2)*arcsin(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{6})$However the complexity of the equation makes it impossible for me to progress past the a2 coefficient.

Comment: Why are there parenthesis in the numerators of the series? Does $(x)^3$ mean something different from $x^3$?

Comment: No they're the same I messed up the latx

Comment: Don't add what you tried in a comment, edit your question.

Comment: The derivative calculator fizzles out after $f^4(x)$ for the representation. The first two terms did appear to follow a pattern, I assumed $RHS=arctan^2(a_1tan(\pi x)+a_2tan^2(\pi x)+..)$ and found a1 and a2 to be $\frac{4}{1√2π^2}$ and $\frac{16.√2}{9π^4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must take care that
$$\frac{3}{2}\arctan^2\left(\sqrt3\,\sum _{i=1}^3 a_i x^i\right)-\text{Li}_2(x)$$ write
$$-x+\left(\frac{9}{2} a_1^2-\frac{1}{4}\right) x^2+\left(9 a_1
   a_2-\frac{1}{9}\right) x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$

Choosing $a_1=\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}}$, the other $a_i=\frac {b_i}{3\sqrt 2}$, the very first $b_i$ are
$$\left\{1,\frac{2}{9},\frac{101}{648},\frac{6907}{72900},\frac{1393
   087}{20995200},\frac{8966875}{185177664},\frac{204870041231}{55
   55329920000},\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: Ohh thank you. I assume these $a_i$ values don't follow a set pattern right?

Comment: @SoapEatr. I am afraid (at least I did find any).

Answer (score 2):

The Sum cannot be represented in terms of elementary functions, however the [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) $\operatorname{Li}_s(z)$ is defined as:
$$\operatorname{Li}_s(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^s}$$
Plugging in $s=2$ yields $$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^2}$$
This special case is called the Dilogarithm or [Spence's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function)$$\\$$we  can see that this is exactly the sum you were looking for,If we call it $S$, then
$$S=\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$$
note that $S$ only converges for $\lvert x\rvert\le1$

Comment: And so the actual question is how to express the Taylor series for $\tan \sqrt{\frac 23 \operatorname{Li}_2(x)}$

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if $\sum sin(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{nx})/n^2$ or some other crazy alternative of the Basel problem could be represented by elementary function